# ASP.NET back and forth between screens

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an application, where a user can start filling a (multipage)form and press back button to navigate to previous screen and continue button to navigate to next screen.

Currently, the page was implemented using the browser's back capability. This causes circular reference

The Scenario is

1. Navigate from page 2 to page 3 click back button on page 3
2. User is now in page 2 and clickint back button pn page 2 will take it to page 3 (because of browser's history has page 3.)

This has to be achieved by using session? How can this be implemented correctly? What options does asp.net provide?

Comment: For #2 are you saying that is what HAPPENS or it's what you WANT to have happen? If I started on page 1, clicked continue to go to page 2, continue to page 3, clicked back I would be on page 2. Click back again I would expect to be on page 1, not 3?

Comment: Personally, I would use Previous and Next buttons and for web forms use a Post-Redirect-Get pattern to navigate between pages of a wizard. Slightly more work but gives you full control of navigating through multiple forms.

Comment: Thanks for your question. Yes on page 2 when the user clicks back it has to take them back to page1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save all steps in session variable, for example of type Queue. When you need return two steps back, simple, two times dequeue and go to uri.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Wizard control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0za4w6.aspx) - it's designed for your sort of scenario where you have multiple pages and you want to go back and forth between them. And you can combine it with AJAX to avoid postbacks :-) ScottGu has a piece on it [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/21/438732.aspx).

Comment: I appreciate your comment. This is a design already in place and suggesting a re write using wizard control is simply not possible (atleast for now.) Any other options would be greatly appreciated. However, I will check the link.Once again, thanks.

Comment: yes things will be much managable using wizard asp.net control